# How to create Marker cluster using mapbox tileset/dataset

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl

[Currently i am able to show only markers on map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZvoV.png)

I am using mapbox as client-side in vue2 as well server side also. So i showing all markers using tileset that i have created on mapbox studio but the issue is this, when i am trying to create marker cluster using tileset/dataset it shows only markers not clusters. Is it possible to show clusters using tileset/dataset or is there any other way to show clusters.

My code is here:

````
    this.map.addSource("ClusterSource", {
        type: "vector",
        url: "mapbox://my_tileset_id",
        cluster: true,
        clusterMaxZoom: 14,
        clusterRadius: 50,
       
      });
      this.map.addLayer({
        id: "clusters",
        type: "circle",
        source: "ClusterSource",
        filter: ["has", "point_count"],
        paint: {
          "circle-color": [
            "step",
            ["get", "point_count"],
            "#51bbd6",
            100,
            "#f1f075",
            750,
            "#f28cb1",
          ],
          "circle-radius": [
            "step",
            ["get", "point_count"],
            20,
            100,
            30,
            750,
            40,
          ],
        },
      });

      this.map.addLayer({
        id: "cluster-count",
        type: "symbol",
        source: "ClusterSource",
        filter: ["has", "point_count"],
        layout: {
          "text-field": "{point_count_abbreviated}",
          "text-font": ["DIN Offc Pro Medium", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
          "text-size": 12,
        },
      });

      this.map.addLayer({
        id: "unclustered-point",
        type: "circle",
        source: "ClusterSource",
        filter: ["has", "point_count"],
        paint: {
          "circle-color": "pink",
          "circle-radius": 6,
          "circle-stroke-width": 1,
          "circle-stroke-color": "#fff",
        },
      });```


[I need to create clusters like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJuGo.png).

Also when i passed my json data for clustering it works but using tileset it does not work
````

Comment: See my post - something can help you
[My issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77780804/mapbox-maps-flutter-markers-and-clusters-live-thier-own-lives-separately-and-clu) Hope it will help