# mapbox_maps_flutter markers and clusters live thier own lives separately and clusters not visible if map's style is any other than MapboxStyles.LIGHT

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

Version mapbox_maps_flutter: ^0.5.1 is being used to render a MapBox in Flutter application

Flutter version 3.16.2

***1. First problem***
The 1st issue I want to highlight that if I apply my own map style other than by default `MapboxStyles.LIGHT`, all `clusters` and `unClusteredLayer` are below the main map layout and not visible - means that I see them during some milliseconds (before map layout was loaded) and later map just covers them. Even if I use `MapboxStyles.DARK` the same problem exists.

***2. Second problem***
Is there any way to combine Markers and Clusters in the way that they know that each other exists on the map?

I render Markers by means of `pointAnnotationManager` and render Clusters as per your example file ([example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-flutter/blob/main/example/lib/cluster.dart)).
Both Markers and Clusters are displayed on the screen, but when some **points** are inside **Cluster** their markers are still visible.
[In example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-flutter/blob/main/example/lib/cluster.dart) YOU use unclusteredLayer instead of Markers. As for the Cluster I found the way how to style it, however as for the `unClusteredLayer` I didn't find any way or example on how to set it as an Image but not a simple circle. Nevertheless, even if I find the way how to set `unClusteredLayer` as an Image I didn't find any way to listen to tap on cluster or on `unClusteredLayer`.

Please, provide a complete example, that includes both clusters and "custom" markers as an Image where these "custom" markers are not visible inside cluster and the way to listen tap on cluster or `unClusteredLayer`.

Here is the my code that is responsible for both Clusters and Markers.

```dart
...

void setMarkers(BuildContext context, List<PlaceEntity> places) async {
    mapboxMap.annotations.createPointAnnotationManager().then((pointAnnotationManager) async {
      var options = <PointAnnotationOptions>[];

      for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        final point = points[i];
        final place = places[i];

        final widget = IEyeMarker(
          place: place,
          onDetailsTap: () {},
        );

        final Uint8List? image = await createImageFromWidget(context, widget);

        options.add(
          PointAnnotationOptions(
            geometry: Point(coordinates: Position(point.lng, point.lat)).toJson(),
            image: image,
            textField: place.id.toString(),
            textColor: 0x00000000,
            iconSize: 1,
          ),
        );
      }

      pointAnnotationManager.createMulti(options);
      pointAnnotationManager
          .addOnPointAnnotationClickListener(AnnotationClickListener(context: context));
    });

    List<Map<String, Object>> features = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
      final point = points[i];
      final place = places[i];
      features.add({
        'type': 'Feature',
        'id': place.id,
        'properties': {
          'point_count_abbreviated': '1',
          'cluster_id': place.id,
          // 'cluster': true,
          // 'point_count': 1
        },
        'geometry': {
          'type': 'Point',
          'coordinates': [point.lng, point.lat, 0.0]
        }
      });
    }

    final data = {
      'type': 'FeatureCollection',
      'crs': {
        'type': 'name',
        'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84'}
      },
      'features': features,
    };

    final layout = {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': data,
      'cluster': true,
      'clusterMaxZoom': 14,
      'clusterRadius': 50,
    };

    mapboxMap.style.styleSourceExists('places').then((value) async {
      if (!value) {
        var source = jsonEncode(layout);
        mapboxMap.style.addStyleSource('places', source.toString());
      }
    });

    mapboxMap.style.styleLayerExists('clusters').then((value) async {
      if (!value) {
        var layer = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/cluster/cluster_layer.json');
        mapboxMap.style.addStyleLayer(layer, null);

        var clusterCountLayer =
            await rootBundle.loadString('assets/cluster/cluster_count_layer.json');
        mapboxMap.style.addStyleLayer(clusterCountLayer, null);

        var unClusteredLayer =
            await rootBundle.loadString('assets/cluster/unclustered_point_layer.json');
        mapboxMap.style.addStyleLayer(unClusteredLayer, null);
      }
    });
  }

...

final points = [
  LatLng(lat: 51.5382123, lng: -0.1882464),
  LatLng(lat: 51.4382123, lng: -0.1982464),
  LatLng(lat: 51.5090229, lng: -0.2886548),
  LatLng(lat: 51.1090229, lng: -0.2786548),
  LatLng(lat: 51.5054563, lng: -0.0798412),
  LatLng(lat: 51.5090215, lng: -0.1959988),
  LatLng(lat: 51.5190215, lng: -0.1859988),
  LatLng(lat: 51.5577676, lng: -0.2008447),
];
```

File "create_image_from_widget.dart":

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

Future<Uint8List?> createImageFromWidget(BuildContext context, Widget widget,
    {Duration? wait, Size? logicalSize, Size? imageSize}) async {
  final repaintBoundary = RenderRepaintBoundary();

  logicalSize ??= View.of(context).physicalSize / View.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
  imageSize ??= View.of(context).physicalSize;

  assert(logicalSize.aspectRatio == imageSize.aspectRatio,
      'logicalSize and imageSize must not be the same');

  final renderView = RenderView(
      child: RenderPositionedBox(alignment: Alignment.center, child: repaintBoundary),
      configuration: ViewConfiguration(
        size: logicalSize,
        devicePixelRatio: 1,
      ),
      view: View.of(context) //PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first,
      );

  final pipelineOwner = PipelineOwner();
  final buildOwner = BuildOwner(focusManager: FocusManager());

  pipelineOwner.rootNode = renderView;
  renderView.prepareInitialFrame();

  final rootElement = RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter<RenderBox>(
      container: repaintBoundary,
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: widget,
      )).attachToRenderTree(buildOwner);

  buildOwner.buildScope(rootElement);

  if (wait != null) {
    await Future.delayed(wait);
  }

  buildOwner
    ..buildScope(rootElement)
    ..finalizeTree();

  pipelineOwner
    ..flushLayout()
    ..flushCompositingBits()
    ..flushPaint();

  final image = await repaintBoundary.toImage(pixelRatio: imageSize.width / logicalSize.width);
  final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

  return byteData?.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

Just for info here is my flutter doctor result:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.2, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-arm64, locale ru-RU)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart-sdk/3.1.5/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/andreifufylev/fvm/versions/3.16.2. Consider
      adding /Users/andreifufylev/fvm/versions/3.16.2/bin to the front of your path.
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.2.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

In order to make muself clear I also included the video and screenshots of my problem where rounded boxes with Image inside are my custom Markers converted from `Widget` to `Uint8List`:

[Without my own custom Markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuJMa.jpg)
[With markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8qfy.jpg)

I expect that custom markers to be not visible/clickable when inside cluster.